# How to proxy a rails app in heroku with a WP blog under same domain

Tags: wordpress, apache, amazon-web-services, heroku, nginx

I have this:

- A rails app on Heroku that servers mydomain.com
- A WP site on another hosting (that I can move to AWS .. or even heroku)

I need that `mydomain.com/blog` serves the WP installation, I DONT want it to be a subdomain for SEO.

My first idea was setup apache / nginx as reverse proxy on a instance on AWS. However I worried that this setup is not optimal as backends are in different services.

It's possible to setup heroku dyno as a proxy? I understand there is no way to modify the system files on heroku, like create a custom nginx setup to do the proxy. I was wondering if there is some application that works as a proxy and can be installed in heroku, next setup the blog in heroku also.

Or it's a good idea to setup an AWS instance as proxy in the same region that the heroku is (us-west1), and setup the blog also there.

I'm interested in the pros and cons of each solution and what would be the best way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had tackled the same exact problem with Rails and WP for quite some time.

My configuration and result:

- Rails app is hosted on heroku (www.sexycrets.com)
- WP Blog is hosted on another server (blog.sexycrets.com)
- When the browser requests [www.sexycrets.com/blog](http://www.sexycrets.com/blog) he receives the same html page that he would have received if browsing [blog.sexycrets.com](http://blog.sexycrets.com) and the url on the browser remains the same

  1. How I achieved it

One solution that does works well for SEO is to use a gem as reverse proxy (I use drewwed/rack-reverse-proxy from Github). You can configure it to intercept the route "/blog" (and "/blog/") so that every time Rails is asked for /blog it loads your WP site with a backend call and returns it to the user. This is a completely transparent operation from the user browser perspective, aside from the delay introduced. The user browser has no way to know that the blog page returned in the response was loaded from another server, the url on the browser remains "www.sexycrets.com/blog".

- Pros: SEO requirements are satisfied
- Cons: Performance since the reverse proxy is not very performant in terms of delay introduced

  2. Alternative

For sake of completeness the other option I tried was to use an iFrame in a static page hosted on heroku that loads the WP. The problem is that in order for it to work avoiding a circular reference all the links in the WP blog have to point to blog.sexycret.com (not www.sexycrets.com/blog) which partly defeats the SEO purpose.

- Pros: Performance is very good since it is not even using Rails: the user browser loads the static /public/blog/index.html page that contains just the iFrame that points to the WP blog
- Cons: the links in the blog are not pointing to the main domain but to the 3rd level domain defeating

Hope this helps!