# Rails website hosted on heroku needs a blog hosted on wordpress is this possible?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, wordpress, heroku

I want to create a solution where I have a rails application hosted on heroku. Needs a blog section which I want to host with wordpress.com.
Is this even possible to host www.example.com on heroku while www.example.com/blog on wordpress.com

Comment: Use a subdomain

Comment: That will destroy my present seo with jekyll blog. Since i have to hand over the solution to client so that they can add blogs via cms like wordpress.com I wanted to host /blog section part only on it. Anyother solution that can save SEO build over some time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to proxy a rails app in heroku with a WP blog under same domain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34688310/how-to-proxy-a-rails-app-in-heroku-with-a-wp-blog-under-same-domain)